# Socket.io event listener called multiple times even though it's emitted only once from my node js server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, sockets, socket.io

So I have a custom socket event listener called newMessage on my AngularJS 1.x client.

Now to help me ask the question better, please think of sessions as a chat we had in a room and going out of the room would be the end of session.

Now,even though my server emits the event "newMessage" only once, my client listener is fired multiple times and the number is equal to the number of sessions we had previously.

So to further explain clearly,
on the first session, it works as expected...
only one message per chat.

But on joining the chat second time, the listener is fired twice. When the third session runs, you guessed it 3 times.

After digging deep through stack overflow, the most probable reason is that I'm adding listener even though that already exists. so this makes the chat app behave in a funny way with same text repeated again in my chat box and being called multiple times.

Can someone please help me how to not keep adding the newMesaage listener if it is already in place. I tried socket.hasListener and add if it does not exist but  it's still not working out

Here are snippets from my code:
Angualar client:

```
socket.on('newMessage', function (message) {
console.log(message);
var html = `<p>${message.from} : ${message.text}</p>`;
$('.chat-box').append(html);
$scope.scrollToBottom();
});
```

Node server:

```
io.in(room).emit('newMessage', generateMessage('Admin:', `Welcome`));
```

also another emit to that event in my server code

```
io.in(room).emit('newMessage', generateMessage(user.username, message.text));
```

generateMessage() is a util js file on my server and it has no problems.

So on every socket.on(newMessage), a peculiar thing happens. it is called multiple times even though on the sever it is only emitting once. And the other interesting thing is it is repeated by number of times we have entered socket connection without disconnecting.

Also on disconnect, (like a reload instead of routing in my angular), the session starts from #1 all over again. but as more sessions happen the behavior I mentioned is observed.

I find this very strange... Someone please help me and it will be really appreciated. Thanks!

**Edit: Adding more code**

This is my socket code in app.js on server. Have given the two methods that emit this event. Other methods I shortened as I found it has nothing to do with regards to this event bug.

```
io.on('connection', socket => {
  var currentRoomId;
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    io.in(currentRoomId).emit('endgameclient');
    onlineRooms.forEach((room, i) => {
      if (room === currentRoomId) {
        onlineRooms.splice(i, 1);
      }
    });
  });
  socket.on('startgame', (secret, callback) => {
    var room = secret.toString();
    var curplayers = players.getPlayerList(room);
    io.in(room).emit('startgameclient', players.getPlayerList(room));
    if (curplayers) {
      io.in(room).emit('newMessage', generateMessage('Admin:', `Game on ${curplayers[0].username} & ${curplayers[1].username}`));
    }
    callback();
  });
  socket.on('createNewMessage', (message, callback) => {
    var room = message.secret.toString();
    var player = players.getPlayer(socket.id);
    io.in(room).emit('newMessage', generateMessage(player.username, message.text));
    callback(null, true);
  });
  socket.on('playerjoin', (joinUser, callback) => {
    ....
  });
  socket.on('getplayers', (secret, callback) => {
    ...
  });
  socket.on('checkplayercount', (secret, callback) => {
    ...
  });
  socket.on('getrooms', (none, callback) => {
    ....
  });
  socket.on('playerleft', (secret) => {
    ....
  });

});
```

And this is my angular client code where I have given two methods that handle messaging.

```
app.controller('TictactoeCtrl', ['$scope', '$transitions', '$http', '$state', '$stateParams', 'authFactory', 'playersService', 'socket', function ($scope, $transitions, $http, $state, $stateParams, authFactory, playersService, socket) {

  socket.on('disconnect', function () {

  });

  socket.on('newMessage', function (message) {
    console.log(message);
    var html = `<p>${message.from} : ${message.text}</p>`;
    $('.chat-box').append(html);
    $scope.scrollToBottom();
  });

  $scope.sendNewMessage = function (e) {
    socket.emit('createNewMessage', { text: $("#message-input").val(), secret: $scope.secret }, function () {
      $("#message-input").val('').blur();
    });
  };

  socket.on('updateplayers', function (players) {
    ....
  });

  socket.on('canstartgame', function (players) {
    ....
  });

  socket.on('startgameclient', function (players) {
    ....
  });

  socket.on('endgameclient', function () {
    ....
  });

  $scope.startGame = function () {
    ...
  };

  $scope.goHome = function () {
    ...
  };
  $scope.logOut = function () {
    ....
  };

  $scope.scrollToBottom = function () {
    ....
  }
}]);
```

Hope this describes my code in greater detail.

Comment: Usually this symptom is caused by adding a socket.io event listener inside a some other event handler, causing you to get duplicate event handlers installed causing you to think the message is being received more than once.  Please show us more of your code so we can see if that is the case.  In particular show us the context around the event handler  that you think gets duplicates so we can advise better how to avoid the duplicates.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment. I read that too on another question, but my socket.on('newMessage') is not scoped within any event handler, be it Angular or socket events.

Its lexical scope is inside the controller for the view and not within any other handler 

Would you like to see more code written in their methods on client and server,  you mean to say by give more context?

Once again thanks!

Comment: We need to see everything that contains where you add the message handler (all containing functions) and how they are called.

Comment: Hey jrfriend00, please check out the question now under edit section. Have added more code from my node js server code and angularjs client code... Do let me know if you can find something amiss with it...

Comment: Hopefully someone who knows angularjs better than I can help you now.

Comment: Have you tested that the listener fires `n` times per message by logging something to the console or are you assuming that due to the growing message?  I ask because it looks like you don't clear the `.chat-box` each time you append to it.  (Also, mixing jQuery with Angular is generally not a best practice.  Ideally you would have `.chat-box` bound to a model instead of manually updating the DOM.)

Comment: Hey sh0ber, I am console logging the messages I'm receiving on 'newMessage event', please see the first line in the event listener in my code, I'm also clearing the .chat-box in 'endgameclient' handler (not seen here, but I'm doing it). Now coming to your question, the listener fires n times per message as I can see in the console.log, the message is displayed n times, this behavior can be explained only if it was called multiple times. Any other causes one can think off? And i'll refactor .chat-box to use model instead of using jQuery. Thanks for the tip...

Answer (score 0):

So I was creating new instances of the socket event handlers every time I came into this angular controller via the view. So even though it was not inside an event handler, it was still being duplicated every time I came to this particular controller and hence the code was behaving this way. So to solve this I simply turned off all event listeners when I left my view with $transition. And voila, it works!

I used off() function by the way.

```
if ($transition.$from().name === 'tictactoe') {
    socket.off()
```

}